# Retrieving the client request ip address

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, ip

This post isn't really a question anymore; I just want to post this to help other people out in the future to avoid lost time.

**Goal**: Retrieve the client IP address and set some specific values based on certain octet in IP.

I was developing a react web-app for my company and needed to support three facilities. The three locations of-course existed in different geographical regions and had slightly different IP schema's.

I needed to set some session identifier based on an octet value from the client IP. To do so, I did the following steps.

1. Setup express route for user to hit on initial visit of app.
2. Get client IP and store in const/var.
3. Explode IP string by `"."`.
4. Perform *If/Then* or *Switch* to determine value of desired octet.
5. Set some session/logic within matching condition.

Thanks to express, the `req` object contains an ip key with the value of the requests IP address. We can utilize this or some other third party library to get the needed info. Of course there are better/more secure ways to do this, but this is a simple method I've researched and setup. Definitely thanks to community for helping me resolve my issue with this.

```
    apiRouter.route('/test')

    .get((req, res) => {
        const request_ip = req.ip;      // Returns string like ::ffff:192.168.0.1
        const ip_array = request_ip.split('.')      // Returns array of the string above separated by ".". ["::ffff:192","168","0","1"]

        // The switch statement checks the value of the array above for the index of 2. This would be "0"
        switch(ip_array[2]) {
            case('0'):
                res.json({'request-ip':ip_array, 'location':'Location A'});
                break;
            case('1'):
                res.json({'request-ip':ip_array, 'location':'Location B'});
                break;
            case('2'):
                res.json({'request-ip':ip_array, 'location':'Location C'});
                break;
            default:
                res.json({'request-ip':ip_array, 'location':'Default Location'});
        }

    })
```

One of my main issues was that I was developing on my local laptop. My node server was running express here. I was also trying to get my request ip from my local machine. This didn't make sense because I was constantly getting back `"::1"` as my request IP. Baffled, I did much research and finally found it to be an obvious [PEBKAC](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pebkac) issue. Thanks to nikoss in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220068/nodejs-ip-address-result-1) post, it made all the sense in the world.

Comment: Is your main goal to find the location of the user rather than getting their ip?

Comment: No, finding the request IP is more important in this scenario. I could use some GeoLocator library I assume is what you mean. I guess I could use the google api for location, but I just need a simple solution for setting some site specific details.  Thanks Joe.

Comment: That's fine I was going to suggest just using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition but if you need IP that's understandable

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion Joe. That, albeit useful, wouldn't be ideal in this scenario IMO. A great alternative option though!

Comment: I've answered with i think would be the easiest/best solution if you need a codepen let me know

Comment: Nah, I get where you're going with that response. I could use that fetch within react to identify the user location/ip schema. Great option. I didn't know about that api. I'll keep this one in mind for future use-case. Appreciate it Joe.

Comment: no worries :) have a nice day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get this information by fetching it from an open IP

https://api.ipdata.co/

```
fetch("https://api.ipdata.co")
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
   }, "jsonp")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.ip)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. This too is useful and a great option!

Comment: FYI, ipdata.co and ipify.org are both blocked by commonly used ad-blockers/chrome extensions.

Answer (score 6):

This works!

```
async componentDidMount() {
      
    const response = await fetch('https://geolocation-db.com/json/');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ ip: data.IPv4 })
    alert(this.state.ip)

}
```

## use it in jsx as

{this.state.ip}

Answer (score 5):

It seems like https://api.ipdata.co doesn't work anymore, even when specifying a key. I ended up using Ipify (typescript):

```
private getMyIp() {
  fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json').then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((res: any) => {
    this.myIp = _.get(res, 'ip');
  }).catch((err: any) => console.error('Problem fetching my IP', err))
}
```

This is a good reference for alternative IP retrieval services: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/257/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-with-javascript-only

Comment: FYI, ipdata.co and ipify.org are both blocked by commonly used ad-blockers/chrome extensions.

Answer (score -1):

If `https://api.ipdata.co` doesn't work you can use `geolocation-db.com/json`. Advantage of geolocation it also gives you other important values like  `latitude, longitude, country, state, zip`

```
fetch(`https://geolocation-db.com/json/`)
    .then(res => res.json())
```

You can `console.log(...)` the `res.json()` to view the JSON values.

Comment: This url provides geo location data that is not accurate

Answer (score -4):

You can use this one as well.

```
fetch('https://get-ip-only.herokuapp.com/') .then(r => r.json()) .then(resp => console.log(resp.ip))
```

https://get-ip-only.herokuapp.com/
This API provides you the IP only.

Comment: Does not work, not a reliable answer